# How to correctly track every open of mail via PHP?

Tags: php, gmail

I send emails via AWS SES PHP API. I need to track every open of my sent mail, so I append 1x1 image to the body of my mail with URL pointing to gateway recording mail opens. But email opens are not tracked correctly, when emails are opened via different mail clients(e.g. Gmail, Mail.ru).

I send following headers in gateway recording mail opens:
Content-Type: image/gif
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="blank.gif"
Cache-Control: no-store

I also send "Cache-Control: no-store" header as the tracking image must not be cached to track all mail opens. In this case every mail open is tracked, but on first mail open 2 requests are sent from browser to load tracking image when opening email via Gmail client or mail.ru client.
And when I send "Cache-Control: no-cache" header, track image loading request is sent only once on first email open

So how can I track email opens correctly?

The tracker image

```html
<img src="tracker.php" width="1" height="1" border="0">
```

Comment: None of the tracking email mechanisms are good, you could use SES open and clock feature but that also has limitation such as multiple notification of same email, email clients has different behaviour as well, e.g: In gmail, Gmail uses it's own IP to fetch the 1 pixel image where in hotmail, it uses client browser to load the image, the image can be blocked in the system or by different filters. You can try SES one to get the appropriate results.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try out AWS SES open and clock feature.